# Vscode Intellinsesnse (autocomplete) like PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Try on VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czaUY.png)

[Only this way?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xA4y.png)

Hey guys!
Please help me, I would like to know if there is any way for vscode to provide the intellisense of attributes inherited from another class, as pycharm does, in vscode I can only access such attributes using a class like the example above.

[I want this way, like pycharm does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7VLY.png)

Comment: Are all 3 screenshots of the same code in different IDEs?

Comment: Hi Josip!

The first two images belongs to VS Code and the last image is the PyCharm, so differents IDEs, thank you!

Comment: I think the intelligent perception search method is also to search according to the object, otherwise it is really cumbersome, especially when there are two methods with the same name. Here is the document：https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: Thank you MingJie!

But i need bring and autocomplete any attributes, methods and every information that main class have.

Comment: I will submit a function request on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

This [problem](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2059) has been solved in version 2022.5.1.